# Pointer help: dereferencing a pointer to a struct accessing data within it

Tags: c++, c, pointers, struct

I'm having some trouble wrapping my head around how a certain line of code works. For some reason it's just not clicking. This line of code is used generally with abstracting file handles in unix domain sockets.

Context:

```
typedef struct myStruct {
    char charArray[10];
} myStruct; 

myStruct myStructure;
myStruct *ptrToStruct = &myStructure;

/* This should change myStructure.charAarray[0] to equal a */
*(ptrToStruct.charArray) = 'a';
```

I understand that an array is essentially a pointer that is pointing to the first index in the array but the pointer has no data (`charArray`).

The reason this is so hard for me to understand is because the `ptrToStruct` is trying to access the pointer's data member `charArray` but the pointer has no data member `charArray` and then it's dereferencing it.

Is this sort of like `(*ptrToStruct).(*charArray) = 'a'`? But the dereferencing operator is being factored out? I apologize for being at all unclear.

---

**UPDATE**: The question has been answered. I was misreading code, the code was actually `*(myStructure.charArray)` and that's how it was altering the first index of the array. I should have also figured this out because as Sid explained pointers do not have the `.` operator.

Comment: `myStruct ptrToStruct` should be `myStruct *ptrToStruct`

Comment: `*(ptrToStruct.charArray)` should be `*ptrToStruct->charArray` or `ptrToStruct->charArray[0]`

Comment: I apologize, you are correct. it is myStruct *ptrToStruct

Comment: `myStruct ptrToStruct = &myStructure;` is wrong because the variable is a structure, not a pointer to a structure,but you're trying to initialize it with a pointer to a structure, not a structure.

Comment: If it's `myStruct *ptrToStruct` then `*(ptrToStruct.charArray)` is not valid.

Comment: I see, so maybe the code i was reviewing was either wrong or i interpreted it wrong.

but my understanding that ptrToStruct.charArray is invalid since that pointer does not have a data member charArray, correct?

Comment: No, the problem is that pointers don't have a `.` operator.  You have to use `->`.

Comment: Thank you that explains it.

Comment: voting to close as a typo

Comment: @codekaizer would it be better if i deleted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ptrToStruct` isn't a struct, so

```
ptrToStruct.charArray
```

should be

```
(*ptrToStruct).charArray
```

or

```
ptrToStruct->charArray
```

Then, yes, you can set the character using

```
*( ptrToStruct->charArray ) = 'a';
```

or

```
( ptrToStruct->charArray )[0] = 'a';
```

This is no different than

```
char charArray[10];
*charArray = 'a';
```

and

```
char charArray[10];
charArray[0] = 'a';
```